# Give an example of a filter that can not be generated by a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, filters

As the title I'm looking for an example of a filter that can't be generated by a sequence.

If you took it from somewhere provide the source please.

Expanding:

Every sequence can generate a filter taking as a base the tails set: if we take $(x_n)$ a sequence $\mathscr{C}=\{\{x_n:n>n_0\}:n_0\in\mathbb{N}\}$ if a filter base for some filter. I am looking for an example of a filter that can not be constructed in this way.

Comment: Could you explain more ? digital filter ? BPF LPF HPL , .... ?

Comment: what is your meaning about sequence ? In general, all the filters are generated by  differential equations not sequences.

Comment: see here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter and this :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function

Comment: @Cardinal: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Davide, filter on what set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction, a filter generated by a sequence has a countable basis. Now the filter of cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ has no countable basis and thus is not 
generated by a sequence.

**Edit**. Denote by $S^c$ the complement of a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose that the filter of cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ has a countable basis $\{F^c_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where each $F_n$ is a finite set. 
Then for each real $r$, the cofinite set $\{r\}^c$ contains an element of the basis, and hence, there exists $n$ such that $F^c_n \subseteq \{r\}^c $, or equivalently, $r \in F_n$. It follows that 
$$
\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}}  \{r\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_n  \subseteq \mathbb{R}
$$
Then $\mathbb{R}$ would be a countable union of finite sets and thus, would be countable, a contradiction.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why it can't have a countable basis?

Comment: I edited my answer.